# jQuery remove or group by same nodes in xml dom

Tags: jquery, xml, parsexml

I'm fairly new on jQuery and manipulating xml doms. So if my question is not releavnt forgive me.

Sample Of My XML:

```
<Urunler>
<Urun>
  <ID>21955</ID>
  <Mensei>Coke</Mensei> /* Contains Same Value */
</Urun>
<Urun>
  <ID>21956</ID>
  <Mensei>Coke</Mensei> /* Contains Same Value */
</Urun>
<Urunler>
```

My Ajax Call and Jquery code to show them into html dom:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'webservice/Resim/Stokkart.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        cache:true,
        success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml) {
        $(xml).find("Urun").filter(function () {
            return $(this).find("ASTipNo").text() == categoryCode;
        }).each(function () {
            $('#product-list').append(
                '<div class="product-name col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>'+
                    '<h5 style="color:red;">' + $(this).find("Mensei").text() + '</h5>'+
                '</div>'
            );
        });
    }
```

What i'm trying to achieve; i want to remove repeating `<Urun>` nodes if they has the same `<Mensei>` values in my xml document or can i merge them into one node (Like `GROUP BY` in SQL)?

PS: I can not do it in server side because i'm developing an offline mobile app on cordova.

Any help will greatly appricated.

Comment: May be @epascarello can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9cdwLta4/

```
    var xmlString = "
<Urunler>
  <Urun>  
   <ID>21955</ID>  
   <Mensei>Coke</Mensei> 
  </Urun>
  <Urun>  
   <ID>21956</ID>  
   <Mensei>Coke</Mensei> 
  </Urun>
  <Urun>  
   <ID>21957</ID>  
   <Mensei>Test</Mensei> 
  </Urun>
<Urunler>";



   var menseiA = [];
   var $xml = $(xmlString);
   var $uruns = $xml.find("Urun");

   //output xml    
    $xml.find("Urun").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).find('ID').text();
        var mensei = $(this).find('Mensei').text();
        console.log(id + ':' + mensei);
    });
    console.log('=====================');

    //finds and removes duplicates
    $uruns.each(function () {
        var mensei = $(this).find('Mensei').text();
        if (jQuery.inArray(mensei, menseiA) !== -1) $(this).remove();
        menseiA.push(mensei);
    });

    //output new xml
    $xml.find("Urun").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).find('ID').text();
        var mensei = $(this).find('Mensei').text();
        console.log(id + ':' + mensei);
    });
```